# longtable list of tables caption problem

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, longtable

I am writing a MS dissertation, and using a long table in my thesis. I have a problem related with the caption of the long table in list of tables(LoT). Table 4.1 which is seen below, is a long table and not convenient for the thesis format for LoT. I want long table to be in the same format like other tables in LoT. I solved the same problem for normal tables and figures by setting `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`. However, it did not work for long table.

> Table 3.5.    Caption.......
>
> 4.1     Caption........
>
> Table 4.2.    Caption......
>
> Table 4.3.    Caption......

The long table is the following. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{ | c | p{3cm} | c | c | c |}
\caption{Basic properties of sensors during deployment.}  \label{table:basic-property-deployment}
\\  \hline
    \textbf{Sensors} & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Threshold} & \textbf{Base Station} & \textbf{Resistance}\\ [6pt]
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{5}{c}%
   % \bigskip 
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ . Basic properties of sensors during deployment} \\
    \hline
     \textbf{Sensors} & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Threshold} & \textbf{Base Station} & \textbf{Resistance}\\ [6pt]
     \hline
     \endhead
     \hline \multicolumn{5}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
     \endfoot
     \hline
     \endlastfoot

     ROWS


\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 4):

It always helps if you post a complete document showing all packages loaded, but as a guess
longtable toc is written by

```
\def\LT@c@ption#1[#2]#3{%
  \LT@makecaption#1\fnum@table{#3}%
  \def\@tempa{#2}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
     {\let\\\space
     \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\protect\numberline{\thetable}{#2}}}%
  \fi}
```

So if you had

```
\makeatletter
\def\LT@c@ption#1[#2]#3{%
  \LT@makecaption#1\fnum@table{#3}%
  \def\@tempa{#2}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
     {\let\\\space
     \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\protect\numberline{Table \thetable.}{#2}}}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Then `Table` would appear in the toc (or use whatever other format your caption style is using in `\addcontentsline`)

Comment: Thank you so much David, you saved my day:)) Your guess is right, it works:) Now another problem occurs, I need a new line between the long table and the subsequent table in LoT. Since, I do not have enough reputation to send an image, I try to describe it below, sorry for that.

Comment: You can use the image upload button but then delete (just) the `!` from the generated markup, that makes a link to the image and someone with edit rights will put the `!` back

Comment: Ok. I think I put the image, actually it does not seem as a serious problem, however I need space between the long table and the subsequent table in LoT as it can be seen in the image.
When I insert new lines in the code you supplied, the dots disappears, and the page number is placed to the next line which I do not want. I need just a space between the long table and the subsequent one in LoT. 


[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iHDj5.png

Comment: Do you have any idea about the spacing problem between the long table entry and next table entry in LoT?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have seen this same spacing issue.  A normal table caption (defined in the documentclass) adds an `\addvspace` that the longtable caption does not. So it seems longtable is somehow overriding the documentclass's caption command (which produces this `\addvspace`).  Oh I just noticed, the `caption` package is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code in the prelude of your .tex file. It will both correct the captions of `longtable`s and lines in the `list of tables`. (based on the answer of [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle), of course).

```
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth}

\makeatletter
  \def\LT@makecaption#1#2#3{%
    \LT@mcol\LT@cols c{\hbox to\z@{\hss\parbox[t]\LTcapwidth{%
    \vskip\abovecaptionskip
    \centering{
      \sbox\@tempboxa{#1{#2 }#3}%
      \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\hsize
        #1{#2. }#3%
      \else
        \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
      \fi
      \endgraf\vskip\baselineskip}}%
    \hss}}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
  \def\LT@c@ption#1[#2]#3{%
    \LT@makecaption#1\fnum@table{#3}%
    \def\@tempa{#2}%
    \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
    {\let\\\space
      \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\protect\numberline{Table \thetable.}{\ignorespaces #2}\vspace\baselineskip}%
    }%
    \fi
  }
\makeatother
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does this do differently from the code in the other answer? Note that you're misusing `\centering`, which does nothing at all inside an `\hbox`, besides not being a command with an argument.

Comment: thanks :)


it converts the default caption format (Table 2.3: Lorem) to (Table 2.3. Lorem) and solve the spacing problem between the long table entry and next table entry in LoT.

`\centering` is needed for captions on the tables to be centered, if not put the captions for tables in the text shift to the left in my case.